# Is differentiability of a function sufficient to conclude that its derivative at the maximum is 0?

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-optimization

Consider the following problem:

$\max_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)$.

Suppose $x^* \in \operatorname{argmax}_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)$ is interior, i.e., $x^* \in (a,b)$.

If $f$ is differentiable and its first derivative $f_x$ is continuous, then we can conclude that $f_x(x^*)=0$.

What if $f$ is differentiable, but $f_x$ is not assumed to be continuous?

Can we still conclude that $f_x(x^*)=0$?

Comment: yes, and it should be the same proof (you don't need the continuity of the derivative)

Comment: The proof goes something like: if $f'(x^*) > 0$, then $f(x) > f(x^*)$ for $x$ just to the right of $x^*$, a contradiction. Similarly $f'(x^*) < 0$ gives a contradiction just to the left. Since $f'(x^*)$ is assumed to exist, we're done.

Comment: Thanks, I was also thinking about that, but I was afraid to be missing something. But probably it is just as easy as it seems.

Comment: If $x^*$ is an interior maximiser then $f(x^*+h) -f(x^*) \le 0$ for **all** small $h$ and so (dividing by $h$ and taking limits) we have $f'(x^*) =0$.